# How do i use hump.timer in a repeat loop in LOVE2D?

Tags: timer, lua, wait, repeat, love2d

How do i make a repeat look in LOVE2D so i can make a character moves?

I've tried

```
function love.keypressed(key)
if key=='left' then
repeat
imgx=imgx+1
timer.after(1,function() end)
until not love.keyboard.isDown('left')
end
end
```

but it didn't worked.Please help me!

Comment: You'd like to move the character or make his sprite image change (not sure because of `imgx`)? You don't need the `hump` module for basic movement.

Comment: i want to use it to move the character.

Comment: arthurgps2: Do you want continuous movement (you have to hold down the button for the character to move very far) or discrete movement (tap the button once and the character moves a whole square or tile)?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to move an image when a key is held down. Using a 3rd party library timer is overly complicated for this.

You want to associate some X and Y variables with the image and draw the image using those variables. You can change them by using the [love.keypressed](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keypressed) callback or by checking for key presses in [love.update](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.update) if you want continuous movement.

Example:

```
function love.load()
    sprite = {x=0, y=0, image=love.graphics.newImage("test.jpg")}
    speed = 3
end

function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("left")  then sprite.x = sprite.x - speed * dt end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then sprite.x = sprite.x + speed * dt end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("up")    then sprite.y = sprite.y - speed * dt end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("down")  then sprite.y = sprite.y + speed * dt end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(sprite.image, sprite.x, sprite.y)
end
```